# How would I access my 2012 MacBook Air's Hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, macbook-air

I recently spilled liquid on my 2012 13' macbook air (4,2) and now I would like to access the data that is (hopefully) still stored on my harddrive. What would I buy to read the data externally, as my laptop is currently not working. Is there a special wire or case that I have to get?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just restore from your regular backups.

Comment: @ta.speot.is If that answer worked for every dead hardware device, like half of superuser questions would be pointless :P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the drive works, [OWC sells a external drive case called the envoy](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MAU3ENVOY12/) both as a standalone product and as part of their upgrade kits. Since apple uses a non standard msata varient (See thread on [askdifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47479/what-is-the-connector-used-by-the-mbas-sata-drive) and [ars technica's article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/06/ivy-bridge-macbook-air-features-revised-ssd-module/)) standard msata adaptors will not work

Answer (score 2):

If your computer boots up at all, it might be possible to use a Thunderbolt cable and target disc mode (http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3838) to transfer your files to another mac. Otherwise, like Journeyman Geek said, your only option is to disassemble the computer with some unusual screwdrivers (http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2011+Solid-State+Drive/6371/) and buy an adapter from OWC.

Comment: Thats the tricky bit here. We really don't have enough information to know what works and what dosen't. I've even heard lots of stories of people having the presense of mind to turn EVERYTHING off, popping the battery (not possible on a MBA ;p), and finding the system more or less works once dried out. Completely forgot about disk mode - it might be a simpler option, depending on how much has fried.